# Find the nonzero entries by row of a sparse matrix and create a new matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a large sparse matrix A of size 300000 by 5000. It is stored as a sparse matrix using the Matrix package in R. I would like to find the nonzero entries of A by each row, and use them to build another matrix called A_clique. I wrote the following code, but it is way too slow. Below is a reproducible code.

```
i <- c(1,3:8, 1000, 300000)
j <- c(2,9,6:10, 4999, 5000)
x <- 1
A <- sparseMatrix(i, j, x = x)
A_clique = matrix(0, nrow = ncol(A), ncol = ncol(A))
for (i in 1:nrow(A)) {
    non_zero_ind_by_row = which(A[i,] != 0 )
    A_clique[non_zero_ind_by_row, non_zero_ind_by_row] = 1
}
```

For small size A, the above code is reasonable. However it is taking way too long for the matrix size I have. I noticed that I haven't used the structure of the sparse matrix, and it gives the entries (row, col) of nonzero entries in A. But I am not sure how to use that information to make my code faster. Your help is appreciated!

Comment: Please make your question reproducible. Supply some sample data and code. Would be nice if you could add timings as well.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I just made the code reproducible.

Comment: You could try taking a look at "ItemMatrix" that the arules package uses. It is also derived from matrix, and is intended for sparse matrices. [Vignette](http://cran.at.r-project.org/web/packages/arules/vignettes/arules.pdf) in CRAN.

Comment: Thanks. The main problem I have is that I would want to avoid the for-loop and compute the matrix A_clique. I will look into the package.